# Flex Half bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to move the image from the right side to the left side? and the form from the left side to the right side? I'm still new to bootstrap so I don't know what to do.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Htx.png)

Here is the html code.

```
  <div class="d-lg-flex half">
    <div class="bg order-1 order-md-2" style="background-image: url('images/register.svg');"></div>
    <div class="contents order-2 order-md-1">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">
              <div class="form-group first">
                <label for="username">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the css.

```
.half, .half .container > .row {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 700px; }

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .half .bg {
    height: 200px; } }

.half .contents {
  background: #f6f7fc; }

.half .contents, .half .bg {
  width: 50%; }
  @media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .half .contents, .half .bg {
      width: 100%; } }
  .half .contents .form-control, .half .bg .form-control {
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 54px;
    background: #fff; }
    .half .contents .form-control:active, .half .contents .form-control:focus, .half .bg .form-control:active, .half .bg .form-control:focus {
      outline: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.half .bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }

.half a {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: underline; }

.half .btn {
  height: 54px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px; }

.half .forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  font-size: 14px; }
```

Please Help I really want to move the image to the left side and the form to the right side. But I don't know how even though I tried to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `order-md-2` class for the img container because it will send the img to the right side .

```css
.half, .half .container > .row {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 700px; }

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .half .bg {
    height: 200px; } }

.half .contents {
  background: #f6f7fc; }

.half .contents, .half .bg {
  width: 50%; }
  @media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .half .contents, .half .bg {
      width: 100%; } }
  .half .contents .form-control, .half .bg .form-control {
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 54px;
    background: #fff; }
    .half .contents .form-control:active, .half .contents .form-control:focus, .half .bg .form-control:active, .half .bg .form-control:focus {
      outline: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.half .bg {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }

.half a {
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: underline; }

.half .btn {
  height: 54px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px; }

.half .forgot-pass {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
 <link rel= stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <div class="d-lg-flex half">
    <div class="bg order-1" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');"></div>
    <div class="contents order-2 order-md-1">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-7">
              <div class="form-group first">
                <label for="username">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/LYjPwjj?editors=1100)

PS: open it in full screen